# How to grab code from another website (that I control)?

Tags: php, html, sql-server, client, remote-access

I want to enter a line of php into my site and have it echo out code that is to be entered on my site. Essentially I am controlling a part of a clients' site and it is more convenient for all involved if I can change it without requiring them to upload it. This must be a long solved issue, but I cannot find a solution. Also, I am not sure if this is possible if my code is server side. Thoughts, help, suggestions?

Comment: When you say you want it to "echo out code" do you mean dynamically write code? As in, have php echo valid php code?

Comment: Do you host the client sites on a shared server?

Comment: WOW would that be a bad idea from a security standpoint...

Comment: You can use eval(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php . It is not only extremely convenient for you and your client; it is also amazingly handy for anyone willing to compromise your client's website quickly and with almost no effort.

Comment: Depending on what exactly you are trying to do, there are certainly better was to do it that are more secure. Can you give a specific example?

Comment: @magma... haha! Love it! That is exactly right. Use eval(); and let everyone use eval(); lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should figure out a different approach to fixing this problem. From the top of my head, you could probably write a utility that allows, with a username and password, you to replace specific files.

Using code from another site, even if you control it, is incredibly dangerous. All a would-be attacker has to do is spoof the address through one of many means, and they could literally do anything on the server that the script has privileges to do. For completeness, you are looking for "[eval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)", but you want to use a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

My thoughts and suggestions... don't do it! Here are a few reasons why:

1. Security: This is the biggest
   reason.
2. Latency: Your clients website will
   run slower because it has to pull
   code across the net in order to
   work.
3. Downtime: What happens when your
   server goes down? It takes down your
   clients server possibly opening it
   up to attacks.

Everything about the idea is bad. There is a line between doing something because you can and doing something because you should. This is definitively as **SHOULDN'T**.

Comment: ok, a security problem. I am not surprised, but could you flesh it out a bit? @cdburgess @David @magma

Comment: when I first thought of this the concept was to read the code off of a page on my site. Is the problem that my site being compromised would endanger the client site?

Comment: Yes. Or the packets can be sniffed mid stream and the hacker could pass something in between to cause the clients site to break in a way that would expose their site to vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Y'know, PHP has [FTP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) support built-in. Maybe you could write a remote deployment app.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ssh was created for:

```
ssh user@remotehost 'execute remote command here'
```

I wouldn't do anything like this in PHP no matter the implementation because it is a huge security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you have PHP echoing out code onto your side, I assume it's php echoing out javascript. This means that you can also print out the js to a different file and link to it.

for example, the php on your server could look like this:

```
echo "function doCoolStuff(){alert("I am awesome!");}\ndoCoolStuff();";
```

on the client's page, you say

```
<script src='freelancerssite.com/codeIneed.php'>
```

This way, the client always gets the code you have on your server.