# How to change clients' site dynamically?

Tags: html, sql-server, security, client, remote-access

So, going from the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734578/how-to-grab-code-from-another-website-that-i-control/) where I was soundly rebuked and for good reason. I want to give clients unique code snip-its that allow me to change a banner ad without requiring them to FTP anything or change their site. Security is clearly a concern. The ad is code, not an image, as we are testing multiple ad networks. So, to summarize:

-client gets a couple lines of code for each place on their site an ad is placed
-I insert code from ad network (adsense, etc) or our own ad for the location without the client needing to lift a finger
-no security breaches or impact on client site

What would be the best approach to this problem? Minimizing developer time and maximizing security...

Answer (score 1):

One of my clients uses Adjuggler to do exactly what you are talking about. The ads are administered by the agency that sells their ads, they just put a little snippet of Javascript on the site and the ads load dynamically based on the settings and campaigns that the agency sets up.

http://www.adjuggler.com/

Comment: Using this model, it probably wouldn't be too tough to scratch-build this either if you needed more flexibility or security.

Comment: Also, this provides many more features then I need and looks as it is built for much larger networks. It is probably too expensive. But the approach of using Javascript sounds right. How much developer time do you think it would take to get this scratch-built? @BrentFriar @bpeterson76

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do. Do you need to weight banners to display some more that others? Do you need to limit impressions? Do you need to track clicks? Do you need to track referrer pages? Do you need to display banners related to keywords on the page? Do you need to offer reporting? You co code a simple random banner display with no features in half an hour. You could also spend a year writing a full featured banner server.

Answer (score 0):

The best and quickest solution would be to install an existing advertisement framework that will allow you or your client to add, remove and edit ads through a web interface.  There are also a number of CMS suites (drupal, CMSMS, Tiki, etc) that either support ad management natively or have ad modules available.  Either solution would require no code be written and allow powerful advertising options.

Comment: this surely would require some code to be written. Wouldn't the CMS need to be installed on the client's site?

Comment: There is no solution that would not need to be installed on the client's site.  If what you want is something that will change the client's site to their specifications and your desires and let you manage advertisements without writing any code, installing anything or spending any time on the problem, *you are looking for a unicorn.*