# How to serve ads using a CMS or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, drupal, content-management-system, ads, remote-access

Based on the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758207/how-to-change-clients-site-dynamically), I am looking for an easy-to-implement solution for serving ads on clients' websites. The code changes on a regular basis, as we test Adsense and other ad networks. Naturally, I do not want to keep bothering the client do ask them to change the code on the site. I want to put a bit of code on their site that stays the same and change it on our end depending on the ad network being used.

A CMS solution has been suggested (drupal, CMSMS, Tiki, etc) however would that not require the CMS to be installed on the clients' sites? Is it possible to use a CMS to generate a couple lines of code that could then serve Adsense, etc dynamically?

Also, I understand that Javascript may be another option. Would that be simpler to implement than a CMS solution? Would it be secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Large networks often iframe the ads to prevent the publisher's CSS or JavaScript affecting the rendering of the ad in any way.

Therefore, at a basic level, all the publisher needs is a bit of JavaScript that sets the iframe with the relevant variables (i.e. which ad to show). The JavaScript to do that is hosted by you so that any updates to the code are propagated to your clients.

Using a CMS like Drupal to host the ads would be pointless and slow. Cache the ad pages and set the right headers (like no etags, etc).

Then you need to push everything (HTML, image and JavaScript) onto a CDN like Amazon's S3.

Comment: Why would a CDN be necessary? How difficult would a javascript solution be to develop? @Blowski

Comment: A CDN would be necessary because most of what you are serving is static content, which CDNs are specifically designed to host. It does depend on the publishers you are targeting - if they are low traffic, but high value (e.g. a subscription-only financial services site, where ads might cost $1000 CPM) a CDN wouldn't be so important. But most ads are low-value, high frequency, so you have to serve 1000 images just to make $5. In that case, you would not break even hosting content that was responsive and reliable from a host like Peer1.

Comment: PS - JavaScript solution: there are already some open source solutions that help with this (OASIS, OpenX). Time to take to code it from scratch would depend on the complexity of the tracking and serving. At a basic level it just requests a random ad from a PHP link and records that it served it. At a more complex level, you could think about unique users, behavioural targeting, dynamic loading, etc. Hence, it really depends on the details.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look At Google DFP and OIO publishers Pro Version.